# Xml components are not loaded into activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask

Edit:

> I just found out that comment the lines that cause the error, he gets
>   the screen all black ... that is, does not load the layout.

I'm trying to get a ProgressBar and a TextView to be able to make changes according to AsyncTask. It is noteworthy that at the time the project was created, the main activity is not this, this (with name SplashScreen) was created later (I'm saying this because I am beginner and I am not aware if something can affect if I left something behind ).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBarTextView);

        try {
            new WSCatalogo91(this).execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

to return rows where do findViewById is always null.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logoSplashScreen"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView android:text="@string/progressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarTextView"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="400dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
```

Comment: If you do not have any Text set or any Maximum / Progress of the Progressbar, these widgets will not be shown in fact of the width attribute `"wrap_content"`. If they do not have any Content, they are invisibile. Try setting any text to the Textview or change the width of the ProgressBar to `"match_parent"`

Comment: @Wicked161089 I just found out that comment the lines that cause the error, he gets the screen all black ... that is, does not load the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setVisibility(int)) of the ProgressBar at the point you wish it to show.

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Also, when it's finished.

```
 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: His ProgressBar is visible at start. Also, findViewById returning null has nothing to do with its visibility. Wrong answer!

Comment: Misunderstood his wording of issue.

Comment: as I can to set the visibility it if I can not get access to it?

Comment: Is this a fragment or activity?